# How to display grid color dynamically using PHP

Tags: php

I have text boxes, and when I start searching it displays result in table.

I am trying to implement a grid.

In this grid I have two colors so 1st row blue 2nd row green then it will come continuously for nxt rows 3rd row ii have blue and the next will be green.

How can I do that ?

Comment: do you think this makes sense to nay one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BY php

```
  <table width="98%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
    <?php 
        $i=1  while....
        if($i%2==0)
        {
        $color = "color1";
        }
        else
        {
        $color = "color2";
        }
    ?>

          <tr bgcolor="<?php $color ?>">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
       <?php   $i++; 
        } // end while  ?>
        </table>
```

By css

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

i think you looking for this

Answer (score 0):

Compute oddity of your row index using modulo or bitwise AND and then apply some css class if odd/even.